# After install ROS Kinetic, cannot import OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I have first installed openCV from source using this [script](http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian).
When I tested it was working well.

After I installed [ROS kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu), and open `python3` and run `import cv2 as cv`, got the following error:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2 as cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

Comment: Your python3 is trying to load a python2 module?! Can you run the following commands and paste the output into your question?: `ldd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so`, `echo $PYTHONPATH`, (in pythonconsole) `import sys; print(sys.path)`,

Answer (score 33):

It looks like this problem is caused by ROS adding `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to the python path.  This actually happens when you activate ROS with the command `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`.  This line is often added at the end of your bashrc file, in `/home/username/.bashrc`.

A workaround is to remove this line from the bashrc file.  This way the python3 opencv packages will be correctly used, and you can still run `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to use ROS.  However, this does mean you cannot use ROS and python3 from the same environment.

Hopefully someone can come up with a better answer, but this should work until then.

Comment: My workaround was not to delete the python path added by ROS but to append the one by anaconda to it e.g
`
export PYTHONPATH="/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" 
`

Comment: Hi. I have commented the line from my bashrc file and also added `sys.path.remove('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/')` in my code. It doesn't show up when I print the paths but still causing trouble when I import cv2. Can you help?

Answer (score 21):

If you are working with anaconda, activate the environment you want to work from, and remove the culprit from `sys.path`.

To do so, open a python3 console, from which:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

You will see several path, among which you should notice:

```
'/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
```

Then remove it:

```
>>> sys.path.remove('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

Tested with python3.5 on anaconda3 with locally compiled opencv. This is likely applicable to `virtualenvs` as well.

For a permanent solution, remove the path `'/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'` from `~/.bashrc` as mentioned in @Paul's answer.

Comment: `print(sys.path)` instead of `print('sys.path')`

Comment: This is not a permanent solution as I need both ros and python3

Comment: @Mehdi Why the downvote? The "permanent" solution originally provided by Paul's answer does allow the use of both ROS and python3. You can ask a new question for your specific problem or write a constructive comment so that you could get some help.

Comment: I do not find the line `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` in my `~/.bashrc` script... it only sources these two files: `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`... Any idea where did ROS sneaks in and changes my sys.path? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

As pointed out, the `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` command in your `.bashrc` modifies the `PYTHONPATH` to be:

```bash
> echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

In my case, since I am using a virtualenv for my Python 3 projects, I just ran the following command to clear the `PYTHONPATH` variable, while the virtualenv is activated.

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

Now, importing `cv2` in Python 3 virtualenv works cleanly. I verified the path of `cv2`:

```bash
In [1]: import cv2
In [2]: cv2.__file__
Out[2]: '<path_to_virtualenv>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
```

To avoid having to run this command every time I activate that virtualenv, I added it to the `/bin/activate` file in the virtualenv directory, as follows:

```bash
...
# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

unset PYTHONPATH

VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/kaiyuzh/pyenv/py3"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
...
```

Comment: this was simple, yet great solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Was having the exact same problem. The issue is that ROS creates it's own cv2.so file for python 2, and then routes every import request to that file. It's a pretty easy fix:

go to your site-packages folder

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

note, if you are using a virtual environment, you must be within that, and should instead do something like:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

Then, force a new sym-link this time using the -f flag

```
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

And that should fix things!

Comment: Can I ask in the final line of code, what is the source and what is the destination? Is the source = virtual environment site packages, and where is the destination? Thanks..

Answer (score 7):

If none of those solutions works for you (as in my case) you could still try to trick your system into importing the right opencv

```
ros_path = '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'

if ros_path in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove()

import cv2 as cv

sys.path.append('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

Maybe you might consider replacing the ros python path at the right location after importing cv2.

It seems that my python had problems importing the correct cv2 even though the path was set correctly, probably because of the weird naming of the python3 cv2 library (cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so) compared to the cv2.so I have in /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Great work :) On python 3.7 sys.path.remove() should be replaced with sys.path.remove(ros_path)

Answer (score 5):

Step1: Find the path where your cv2.so is installed (if you use the python-cv wheel to install the opencv)

Step2: Export the path to your .bashrc or .zshrc file, just like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-package‌​s:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Thanks to [@lxrd-aj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2468129/lxrd-aj)

Answer (score 4):

I tried to
remove `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so.`
Now It is working.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I also encounter this problem. I just commented-out the source:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

and then, open the terminal, In the anaconda lib path I executed:

> sudo ln -sf /home/apg/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
>   /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so

`/home/apg/miniconda3` is the path where my python3 was installed, and `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so` was the path that `opencv-python` was installed.

I don't know yet why this command works, but it did work for me to solve the problem that I was not able to import cv2 previously.

Comment: And after I executed this,the cv2.so in /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so has become a broken link.

Answer (score 2):

During ROS setup running `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, the script between other things will go to every distribution package for python2 and python3 and it will add it to the python system path. When you try to `import cv2` using Python **3** it will first find the OpenCV binding for Python **2** as included in the path.

If you are not planning on using python2.7 at all for your ROS project, consider removing entirely the python2.7 OpenCV package, so it won't be added to the path when running the ros setup script:

`$ rm /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so`

Another more gentle approach if you are planning to use both Python versions would be to create two virtual environments with the correct bindings, and activate one or another depending on your requirements.

Comment: This worked for me. I am still able to import cv2 and rospy in both Python2 and Python3. Removing this simply means you have to use your own installed opencv, which can be done though pip.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem over here. As others suggested, `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` appends a path to ROS opencv in the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

If you are working with multiple `virtualenv`s and you need a solution that will work in most of the cases, then you can put the following code snippet in your `.bashrc`:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
array=( $(find ~/.virtualenvs/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) )

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
  export PYTHONPATH="$i/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
done
```

So the idea is that if you have a centralised directory of all of your `virtualenv`s (e.g when you use `virtualenvwrapper`) we can search for those directories using:

```
$(find ~/.virtualenvs/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

given that all of our `virtualenv`s are under `~/.virtualenvs`. This should give us a list of all of our `virtualenv`s root directory.

We are then looping over the array of virtualenv directories and we are appending their path (e.g `~/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`) to the `PYTHONPATH`. Note that this should be done just **after** the `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`.

It's not a perfect solution to the problem as you can still get conflicts if two envs have different opencv versions, but for the initial problem, at least it should work.

Alternatively, you can just manually do the same trick for the desired virtualenv:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had previously installed ROS and catkin_tools on Ubuntu 16.04 and suddenly experienced the same issue. 
Fixing it worked as follows:

1. Navigte to home directory
2. Open `.bashrc` in editor (often this file is hidden by default; if so, make it visible by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>)
3. Comment out or remove the two lines `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. Commenting out works by putting an `#` in front of the two respective lines.
4. Save file
5. Restart PC

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily remove the *ROS PATH* and `import cv2`.

Here's my solution to deal with that problem:

```py
try:
    import cv2 as cv
except ImportError:
    import sys
    ros_path = '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
    sys.path.remove(ros_path)
    import cv2 as cv
    sys.path.append(ros_path)
```