# Unable to import cv2 and cvbridge in ROS and python3

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ros

**Environment**

1. Ubuntu 16.04
2. Python 3.5.2
3. Ros Distribution-Kinetic

Ros was installed as per installation instruction (**sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-full-desktop**)
And to make the **Python3** as default version, I followed the necessary and sufficient step of install python3 versions of rospkg and catkin(**sudo pip3 install rospkg catkin_pkg**).
After which i am able to import cv2 in python2 but not in python3 as below

**ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type**

To solve this I install the opencv3 with (**pip3 install opencv-python**) and then force a symbolic link as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019951/after-install-ros-kinetic-cannot-import-opencv)
But then i am unable to use cv bridge and get the below error

```
from cv_bridge.boost.cv_bridge_boost import getCvType
```

**ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv_bridge_boost)**

So whats the right way to install ROS such that the python version is python3 and am able to import opencv and corresponding dependencies?

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221565/unable-to-use-cv-bridge-with-ros-kinetic-and-python3?rq=1