# cv_bridge dynamic module does not define module (PyInit_cv_bridge_boost)

Tags: opencv, ros

Problems in using cv_bridge to convert ROS image to OpenCV image.

I created a virtual environment with Python 3.7.2 and OpenCV.
I can import by using "import cv2"

The problem is in this line:

`cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data,"bgr8")`

What I want to do is to get an image from ROS topic and display in `cv2.imshow`

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function
>   (PyInit_cv_bridge_boost)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use cv\_bridge with ROS Kinetic and Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221565/unable-to-use-cv-bridge-with-ros-kinetic-and-python3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though opencv2 could be import in python 3.7, there were some problems in using `cv_bridge` library. Solved by running my code using python older version (2.7). (`python2 code_name.py`)