# Building cv_bridge Package with ROS Kinetic and Python3 ignoring Cmake Arguments

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, cmake, ros

I'm trying to integrate a ROS package into our system for a research project and the cv_bridge package and python3 is needed in order to get the package working. Currently I can't get the cv_bridge package to build in python3 despite multiple steps, constantly builds in python2 directory.

Working in Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS kinetic. Using python3.5

Error Message:

```
[ERROR] [1563897986.999724]: bad callback: <function color_callback at 0x7f00ffa06598>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
  File "/home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/src/rcnn_apple_detector/detection.py", line 84, in color_callback
image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image_msg, "bgr8")
  File "/home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/python/cv_bridge/core.py", line 163, in imgmsg_to_cv2
dtype, n_channels = self.encoding_to_dtype_with_channels(img_msg.encoding)
  File "/home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/python/cv_bridge/core.py", line 99, in encoding_to_dtype_with_channels
return self.cvtype2_to_dtype_with_channels(self.encoding_to_cvtype2(encoding))
  File "/home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/python/cv_bridge/core.py", line 91, in encoding_to_cvtype2
from cv_bridge.boost.cv_bridge_boost import getCvType
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv_bridge_boost)
```

I've tried the steps in this previous question's answer:

[Unable to use cv_bridge with ROS Kinetic and Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49221565/11821473)

> "You are right, you should build cv_bridge with python3.
>
> You can do it with passing -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
>   -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so args to cmake. Or, if you are using catkin to build packages, you can do next
>   steps:"

The only variations to the steps is I have to use catkin_make because issues with a bunch of older packages I'm using aren't currently working with catkin build. I don't know if that is causing it or not. But I pass the cmake arguments into my workspace and still it targets to the ROS python2 directory.

Location cv_bridge is currently still being built:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Version:

```
apt-cache show ros-kinetic-cv-bridge | grep Version
Version: 1.12.8-0xenial-20190320-142632-0800
```

catkin config:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/devel
Install Space:     [missing] /home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/install
Log Space:         [missing] /home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/rival/Documents/Repos/ROS/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        merged
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
```

Exact steps taken:

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools python3-dev python3-catkin-pkg-modules python3-numpy python3-yaml ros-kinetic-cv-bridge

catkin clean

catkin config -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so

cd src/vision_opencv/
git checkout 1.12.8

catkin_make cv_bridge

source devel/setup.bash --extend
```

I expect cv_bridge to be built with the cmake arguments but it still gets targeted back into the python2 directory. It seems the cmake args are being ignored/not targeting correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this [blog post](https://medium.com/@beta_b0t/how-to-setup-ros-with-python-3-44a69ca36674).

Essentially you need to create new catkin workspace so that its configuration doesn't mess with your original (python2) workspace.

1. Install python3 and dependencies. I like using `--user` without sudo to make resolving dependency conflicts a little easier.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools python3-dev python3-numpy 
   sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-yaml
   pip3 install rospkg catkin_pkg --user
   ```
2. Make a new workspace

   ```
   mkdir py3_catkin_ws
   cd py3_catkin_ws
   mkdir src
   ```
3. Init catkin with python3 configured (use your python3x version)

   ```
   catkin config -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
   catkin config --install
   ```
4. Clone and `catkin build` [vision_opencv](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv.git) in your new workspace. Continue as usual. Python3 should now be able to locate `cv_bridge`. The blog post suggests to `source install/setup.bash --extend` but it wasn't necessary in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue under ROS Melodic, Ubuntu 18.04 and using conda to separate the environments. I started to get some strange errors, like NumPy not being found. At this point it was too much of a hassle and a possible waste of time.

This was especially annoying as I could launch my ROS node using Python 3 and OpenCV worked perfectly well, only the transfer from ROS to CV was missing...

I ended up just copying the lines from `cv_brdige` that did the translation to my package and made the translation without importing `cv_bridge` package.

As ROS is getting more [Python 3 friendly](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic), and packages will hopefully follow, this will not be an issue in the future.