# opencv import issue and double install

Tags: linux, python-3.x, opencv

Previously ROS was installed in my system which requires opencv for its implementation and now I am using anaconda in which I need to use the opencv library once again. While writing python code `import cv2` throws an error `module not found`.

> Is there any way to use that opencv library which ROS installed in anaconda

Although I installed opencv once again using conda.

```
$conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

however opencv-3.3 was installed using above command. Now my python code is showing different import error as shown below:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-6b49ad4d4ca5> in <module>()
      1 from random import shuffle
      2 import glob
----> 3 import cv2
      4 shuffle_data = True  # shuffle the addresses before saving
      5 hdf5_path = 'dataset.hdf5'  # address to where you want to save the hdf5 file

ImportError: /home/kamal/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

How can I particularly specify which opencv library to use. What env variables I need to change.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After install ROS Kinetic, cannot import OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019951/after-install-ros-kinetic-cannot-import-opencv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncommenting the line `source /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/setup.bash` in the .bashrc file dosen't help. You also need to remove the extra`sys.path` added by the ROS environment.
In a python console

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

you will see multiple paths related to ROS
then remove the unwanted part of the path by

```
sys.path.remove('unwanted_path')
```

This will solve the problem but now ROS will not work. To make it work you need to append the removed path again.
If someone has a better approach please answer.