# Couldn't import cv2 in GCP ml-engine (runtime version 1.8)

Tags: google-cloud-ml

When using runtime version 1.8, i'm getting this error when I tried to import cv2:

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv9Algorithm7getListERSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS7_EE`

Anyone knows if there's any workaround? Looks like glib needs to be installed in the image, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud ML images already has installed the [python-opencv](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list#supported_cloud_ml_engine_runtime_versions) package. If you are facing the issue in your local environment instead of CloudML, most probably you have dependencies problems, for example when [two different programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019951/after-install-ros-kinetic-cannot-import-opencv) modify the same package. Other similar threads that solved the issue are:

- Related to [PKG_CONFIG_PATH](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11273#issuecomment-379738275).
- Related to [differences between pip versions 2.7 and 3.4](https://github.com/CharlesShang/FastMaskRCNN/issues/111#issuecomment-317221902).

I found this tutorial that may be useful for you [Running a Spark Application with OpenCV on Cloud Dataproc](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-dataproc-opencv/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0).