# can't run the sugiyama.py example from the flow example folder

Tags: flow-project

I followed the download instructions and got the conda env to work
but when i tried to run the example program I got a message that I did not know how to fix

Seems to think that opencv is in python2?
any thoughts on why this is happening?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "examples/sumo/sugiyama.py", line 11, in  
from flow.envs.ring.accel import AccelEnv, ADDITIONAL_ENV_PARAMS  
File "/home/airlab/Desktop/RL-Traffic-Lights/flow/flow/envs/init.py", line 2, in
from flow.envs.base import Env  
File "/home/airlab/Desktop/RL-Traffic-Lights/flow/flow/envs/base.py", line 10, in
from flow.renderer.pyglet_renderer import PygletRenderer as Renderer  
File "/home/airlab/Desktop/RL-Traffic-Lights/flow/flow/renderer/init.py", line 3, in
from flow.renderer.pyglet_renderer import PygletRenderer  
File "/home/airlab/Desktop/RL-Traffic-Lights/flow/flow/renderer/pyglet_renderer.py", line 7, in
import cv2  
ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43019951/5028532

Comment: This has to do with your pythonpath over anything else. You can fix this however by running `pip install opencv-python` in your flow environment. That way it will find it before it hits your ros installation.